# How do I disable Microsoft's link rewriting on my MSN account?

Tags: email, msn

Microsoft has recently deployed a mail corrupting feature they call (one has to laugh) ["Advanced Threat Detection"](https://products.office.com/en-us/exchange/online-email-threat-protection), which is an [unmitigated disaster](https://blog.tylerbickford.com/2016/06/16/microsoft-advanced-threat-protection-is-a-disaster/) in almost every imaginable way. It's chief "feature" (at least as I experience it as an end user) is the rewriting of nearly all links in received e-mails, like say

```
http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/tmam20/10/1
```

to

```
https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.tandfonline.com%2ftoc%2ftmam20%2f10%2f1&data=01%7c01%7cbickford%40PITT.EDU%7ca9f7b386fae94ca994bb08d38e3a59bb%7c9ef9f489e0a04eeb87cc3a526112fd0d%7c1&sdata=st79jNKGyGbI%2fcDprP%2fgra%2fTQz7lni5uZCS7a1W83OI%3d
```

(Really!)

How do I disable this on my `msn.com` e-mail account?

Answer (score 0):

It takes some doing, but eventually the Outlook Research Team was able to disable this feature.

If you want this disabled, follow the usual links to help (the "?" in the `outlook.com` UI) and ask for a member of the Outlook Research Team to contact you directly by mail. They will be able to disable the feature within 24 hours.

It turns out that this many users' experience of this feature was indeed a bug:

> Only those links which were deemed to be suspicious were supposed to redirect to a warning page [...] however the change affected all the links and our engineering team had to get it corrected.